# Can't get Mac to detect installation media

Tags: installation, dual-boot, mac

Note: I am following these instructions: [Dual Boot OS Ubuntu -OMG Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/dual-boot-os-ubuntu).

So, for the past few days I've been trying to install Ubuntu on my Mac OSX because I would really like that extra option of using Ubuntu instead of Apple's OS.
Easy enough, right? Well, I first tried installing via a usb but that didn't work (it kept saying my USB was unreadable) so I decided I would use one of my blank DVD-RWs. I downloaded the Ubuntu file and inserted my blank DVD-RW and it just kept spinning until it was ejected by my Mac. It's not the hardware because it is accepting video DVDs, it just plain won't accept it.

I decided burning the .iso file from my PC would work, after burning it on my PC I inserted it into my Mac, but my Mac still couldn't read the DVD. What am I doing wrong? My Mac's processor is x64.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by taking the img file I created, transferring it to my PC, and burning that img to a blank DVD-R. For some reason, Mac then was able to read the DVD.

Comment: Well... Yeah, you need to burn the image file into a DVD or use a LiveUSB creater to make a bootable disc/USB stick. Otherwise the media is just simply a DVD or USB stick that has an image file. Can't boot off of that!